# Python created SQL sent via Slack and then run in pgAdmin has invisible characters which results in " is not a known variable" for tables

Tags: python, slack-api, postgresql-9.6

I'm still using PostgreSQL 9.6 (specifically 9.6.22) and was creating partitioned child tables for next year's data. I decided to automate this annual creation by creating a function that creates 12 tables for the following years.

The tables created successfully. I can see them in pgAdmin4, I can query them (there's no data). But when I try to update the trigger function on the parent table. **Important note**, I created the SQL for the new logic (the 12 new months in 2022) using a loop in Python and then I sent it to myself via Slack before pasting the new code into pgAdmin.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION here.ta_insert_trigger()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF SECURITY DEFINER
AS $BODY$
BEGIN 

IF (NEW.tx >= DATE '2022-12-01' AND NEW.tx < DATE '2022-12-01' +INTERVAL '1 month') THEN
    INSERT INTO here.ta_202212
    VALUES (NEW.*)ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
ELSIF (NEW.tx >= DATE '2022-11-01' AND NEW.tx < DATE '2022-11-01' +INTERVAL '1 month') THEN
    INSERT INTO here.ta_202211 VALUES (NEW.*)ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
--and so on to this year's tables
ELSIF (NEW.tx >= DATE '2021-12-01' AND NEW.tx < DATE '2021-12-01' +INTERVAL '1 month') THEN
 INSERT INTO here.ta_202112 
VALUES (NEW.*)ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
ELSIF (NEW.tx >= DATE '2021-11-01' AND NEW.tx < DATE '2021-11-01' +INTERVAL '1 month') THEN
 INSERT INTO here.ta_202111 
VALUES (NEW.*)ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
--and so on
ELSE 
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'tx out of range.  Fix the ta_insert_trigger() function!';
END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$;
```

When I run this I get the baffling error

```
ERROR:  "here.ta_202212" is not a known variable
LINE 14:     INSERT INTO here.ta_202212
                         ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 369
```

I tried copying the table name from a `SELECT` query window. If I change the first table name that gives an error to one of the previous year's table names I still get that error with the old table name. I'm baffled. I've compared the two lines and they look exactly the same. They're both coloured the same in pgAdmin4.

After thinking it might be an issue with an invisible character, when I paste the new SQL into VSCode it highlights the white space before the first `INSERT` and says that it's made up of invisible `U+00a0` characters. It seems like that is true, the Python I used to create the sql is below, but I'm still very confused how this was generated and how to catch it in the future.

```py
    insert_statement = '''IF (NEW.tx >= DATE '{year}-{month}-01' AND NEW.tx < DATE '{year}-{month}-01' +INTERVAL '1 month') THEN
    INSERT INTO here.ta_{year}{month} VALUES (NEW.*)ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;'''
```

Comment: What is `here`?  Is that the current username or schema?

Comment: it's the schemaname. Normally I would obfuscate these object names but I was just so baffled in this situation that I had to include exactly the code I was trying to run

Comment: Perhaps you need quotes around the schema and table name?  i.e. `"here"."ta_202212"`?